# Scaling Markers on Zoom Change

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, scaling

For a Christmas Market, I'm currently working on a Google Maps map. I load a sprite of different icons representing the market boothes in their different sizes:

[image]

(the greyed out version is for deactivated status):
http://www.felixkittler.de/area51/googlemaps/buden.html

Everything works fine so far, as long as the user does not zoom in or out - if so, the boothes are not scaled and consequently seem far too big or small.

I thought I might predefine another set of icons, containing the same markers, but with scaled markerImages. Unfortunately, I can't get this to work:

```
for(i=0; i<markerSizes.length; i++){
    var aktiv = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "http://www.felixkittler.de/area51/googlemaps/buden/SPRITE.png", 
        new google.maps.Size(markerSizes[i], 27, "px", "px"),
        new google.maps.Point(85, i*30),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Size(markerSizes[i]*2, 14) //this doesn't work!!!
    );
    gicons_aktiv.push(aktiv);
}
```

I do not yet track the zoom_changed event, but I set up a version of my file which should use the scaled icons:
http://www.felixkittler.de/area51/googlemaps/buden_scaled.html
(scaling up (x2) in lines 116 & 125).

Any ideas how to solve this problem?
Since this is not the only sprite I'm using, I would like to avoid uploading multiple resolutions of the same sprite, scaling up or down would be much more convenient.

Thanks!!!

Comment: May be useless info, but it seems that custom added sprites don't change size proportionally to the map. I have also tackled this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I just found out by myself.
Thanks to Marc Ridey for [this blog post](http://blog.mridey.com/2010/03/using-markerimage-in-maps-javascript.html)!

Marker Image for original size:

```
var original = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    "http://www.path/to/sprite.png", 
    new google.maps.Size(markerSizes[i], 24), //marker height=24, width in array
    new google.maps.Point(0, i*30), // each row of the sprite grid is 30px tall
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    null // use file dimensions 168 x 270px
);
```

Marker Image for displaying marker scaled 50% down:

```
var half = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    "http://www.path/to/sprite.png", 
    new google.maps.Size(markerSizes[i]/2, 12),
    new google.maps.Point(0, i*15),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Size(84, 135) // original dimension of sprite: 168 x 270 px
);
```

Hope this helps anyone (: